# I cant see the value when using mapstruct with a JsonNullable field

Tags: java, swagger, mapstruct

In my mapstruct interface, i have a method to convert a Long to a JsonNullable which is the waited type by the swagger generated class (cause of nullabe=true) :

```java
    default JsonNullable<BigDecimal> map(Long value) {
        return value != null ? JsonNullable.of(BigDecimal.valueOf(value)) : JsonNullable.undefined();
    }
```

When i'm in debug, it's ok, JsonNullable has : present=true, value=80 for example.
When i'm testing with a rest client, i don't have the value in the response :

```json
"montant": {
            "present": true
        }
```

Do you know why and what to do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the README of [jackson-databind-nullable](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/jackson-databind-nullable#usage)

you should register the module `JsonNullableModule` on Jackson `ObjectMapper`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.registerModule(new JsonNullableModule());
```

Insted of doing it programmatically, you can define a bean of the module:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JsonNullableModule jsonNullableModule() {
        return new JsonNullableModule();
    }

}
```

that will be automatically registered, thanks to [JacksonAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.9.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.html)